# How much energy is needed to accelerate a Muon to 95 percent the speed of light $c$?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity, particle-physics, kinematics

I would like to know how much energy is required to accelerate a Muon (A quantum particle part of the lepton family). Its mass is 105.7 MeV. I don't have much experience on using the relativity equation (As I am only in grade 9).

Comment: Welcome to Physics Stack Exchange! This is a great site for physics questions and answers. We have some rules to make sure the quality of the site is high. For example, posts like this one must *show effort* and ask a specific question. Please at least write down some basic equations and see if you can make any progress. If you get stuck, then ask a specific question and we'll help.

Answer (score -1):

It requires no energy if it’s speed is already .95 c. (An object in motion tends to stay in motion...) I assume you mean accelerate it from when it is at rest?

You need to look at the relativistic energy equation. The particle's initial energy is 
it's rest mass, $E_0$. It's final energy $E_f = \gamma E_0$, where $\gamma$ is a term that pops up all the time in relativity and depends on the velocity.

The difference between these two quantities is the energy needed to accelerate it in a vacuum to the desired velocity.